# How to know if a list of prices are mean-reverting?

Tags: correlation, econometrics, cointegration

I have two historical price lists with the following columns

> **data - price**

Now i have to create the ratio between the prices of these lists:

> **list A:** 01/01/2011 10.50
>
> **list B:** 01/01/2011 23.89

I compare the date of the lists, if the day is the same I find the ratio, doing:

> **ratio** = 10.50 / 23.89

Ok... I do this division for each price of the lists.

The result should be:

```
0.4395   0.4400   0.4289   0.4361
```

Now the question is: **How could I check if this serie (ratios) is mean reverting?**

Answer (score 4):

The answer below follows the definition taken from J.Exley et al article on [Mean reversion](http://www.actuaries.org.uk/sites/all/files/documents/pdf/Exley_Mehta_Smith.pdf): *Discrete time mean-reverting process is a stationary process.*

Let $R_t$ is your ratio, and $\mu$ is the mean value of this ratio, then mean-reverting process could be expressed as an $AR(1)$ process of the form:

$$ R_t -\mu = \alpha (R_{t-1}-\mu) + \sigma W_t $$

Stationarity tests are many: (A)DF, PP, KPSS tests all are common part in most of the statistical software. If you suspect that the data may have structural changes than you may consider Zivot-Andrews test. For $R$ users an `urca` library is essential in testing for stationarity.

Comment: Thank you so much. I have a doubt, please take a look at: http://quanttrader.info/public/testForCoint.html he is using "tseries" library and it seems A(DF) stationarity tests. My questions are: 1. do i have to see urca or tseries? 2. How can I understand what stationarity test is "better"(more accurate) for my test? Thank you!

Comment: @Dail, the choice of the test depends on the properties of ratio as the time series process, if your true data generating process follows an AR(1) as it is shown in the reply a simple DF test will do all the work. If you're not so sure the augmentations like ADF and PP for more robustness could be used. But more steps and parameters lowers efficiency if it comes for true AR(1) model. If the data has some structural changes in mean then you may consider Zivot-Andrews. Go from simple to more complicated, study residuals and decide if the results are satisfactory. `urca` just collects all tests.

Comment: KPSS is nice if you want to emphasize mean-reversion as your primary goal not the rejection of the property. You may use `tseries` however for `adf.test` that also includes DF as a particular case.

Comment: My first goal is to check if the series are correlated, and i use Pearson method to do it. Then we i find correlates series i have to check if the price reverting to the mean. What do you mean with:  "If the data has some structural changes in mean then you may consider Zivot-Andrews" ? after those check i think i have to use angle-granger method, i'm a bit confused :|

Comment: @Dail, if you know that in your price data some changes in explanatory variables happened (new products, brands, shops, other prices, income etc.), the process will still be mean-reverting, however to a different mean, since the latter could change due to the mentioned facts. If not and picture of $R_t$ looks stationary, then (A)DF will be ok. Well Engle-Granger goes for cointegration, it's a bit different story.